# Filter based on parameter

Tags: python, python-requests

My filter url is,

```
url = "example.com/..../Item?&$filter=INKA_number%20eq%201774261"
```

I want to pass this as parameter in request.get() method

```
url = "example.com/..../Item"
requests.get(url, headers, authentication)
```

How to add filter in above request insetead of directly in url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the query parameters using `parse_qs` function defined within the `urllib.parse` module.

```
>>> url = "example.com/..../Item&$filter=INKA_number%20eq%201774261"
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qs
>>> result = parse_qs(url)
>>> result
{'$filter': ['INKA_number eq 1774261']}
```

So to pass the query parameter to `request.get` you could do

```
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qs
>>> requests.get(url, headers, authentication, params=parse_qs(url))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```
payload = {'$filter': 'INKA_number%20eq%201774261"'}

r = requests.get(url, headers, authentication, params=payload)
```

Comment: It is not working. It throws results without filter :(

Comment: What is the output of `r.url`? **Typo**: it's not `filter` but `$filter`. My bad.

Comment: even this didnt work, but the solution given by @Abdul(pfb) worked